# Clarification on a Detail in the Born-Oppenheimer Approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, born-oppenheimer-approximation

In treatments of the Born-Oppenheimer approximation, people take the adiabatic states to be real eigenfunctions of the electronic Hamiltonian. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Oppenheimer_approximation) states "The electronic wave functions $\chi_k$ will be taken to be real, which is possible when there are no magnetic or spin interactions." Can someone expand on why this is justified? I've seen this statement a few times now and all without explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Hamiltonian is real (as the Coulomb Hamiltonian is) then the wave function can always be chosen to be real. This is because, if you suppose $\psi(x) = \psi_1(x) + i \psi_2(x)$, then it is easy to verify that $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$  must separately be eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian; in turn, this means that either they differ by a multiplying complex factor (which can be factored out) or that they are distinct *real* solutions with the same energy. In either case we can therefore restrict ourselves to real-valued functions.